# icloud calendar integration: How to get the List of all events in the calendar using Node js API

Tags: node.js, icalendar

I found two libraries..

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/apple-icloud
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/icloud-calendar

Documentation in both seems minimal and they didn't work. Any suggestion /alternative?

Comment: did you manage to find a way to do this? I have been looking over the internet for 2 days and can not see anything.